# ASP.NET : how to make reliable long running event consumer

Tags: asp.net, task, event-bus

I am considering on the way to implement event consumer as long running task in ASP.NET. The common way to do this it use `IHostedService` and it implementation `BackgroundService`, but what exactly is the difference between class I show below when I set it as singleton?

One of advantage of this class is possibility to implement interface we want to use.

```
public class LongRunningTask
{
    private readonly Task _mainLopp;

    public LongRunningTask()
    {
        _mainLopp = Task.Factory.StartNew(MainLoopAsync);
    }

    public async Task MainLoopAsync()
    {
        while(true) //here we can use cancellation token or something else
        {
            await SomeAsyncMethod() //like client.ReceiveEventAsync()
        }
    }
}
```

I see this solution in RabbitMq library.